# unable to fetch data from mongodb

Tags: mongodb, typescript, postman, nestjs

Am working on nestjs and i want to fetch data from the collection on the basis of 'name' value.But i got output like this:

[image]

code of services:

```
async find_one(name):Promise<Usersinterface>{
    const data=this.usersmodel.find(name).exec()
    return data;
}
```

code of controller:

```
@Get('getitem')
async getitem(@Body()name):Promise<any>{
    return this.usersService.find_one(name)
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should pass an `object` as a `filter` to the `find` method

so in the service, the query should look something like

```
find({ name: name })
```

the key (the first name) is the name of the property in your collection

the value (the second name) is the value you passed to the function

```
async find_one(name):Promise<Usersinterface> {
    const data = this.usersmodel.find({ name: name }).exec()
    return data;
}
```

hope it helps